# Pesquisa aparece duplicada no AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android

Estou com um certo problema ao utilizar o `AutoCompleteTextView` do Android.

O `AutoComplete` está me apresentando dados duplicados por estar pesquisando tanto no nome quanto no email. Eu gostaria que ele apresentasse somente um valor, quer seja pesquisando pelo nome do contato, quer seja pesquisando pelo email.

Basicamente, eu tenho uma lista que armazena um `HashMap` contendo o nome e o email de cada contato:

```
List<Map<String, String>> contact_list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Para preencher o `Hashmap`, eu uso um `Cursor` para me ajudar a buscar as informações do Banco de Dados:

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(ContactTable.SELECT_ALL, null);

if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
     while(cursor.moveToNext()){
         Map<String, String> contact_info = new HashMap<>();
         contact_info.put("name", cursor.getString(ContactTable.COLUMN_CONTACT_NAME_IDX));
         contact_info.put("email", cursor.getString(ContactTable.COLUMN_CONTACT_EMAIL_IDX));
         contact_list.add(contact_info);
     }
}
```

Depois que eu adiciono todas as instâncias do `HashMap` na minha lista, eu adiciono essa lista em um `SimpleAdapter` e seto este *adapter* em meu `AutoCompleteTextView`:

```
auto_adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        mContext,
        contact_list,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
        new String[]{"name", "email"},
        new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});
auto_complete.setAdapter(auto_adapter);
```

O `threshold` possui valor "1" e foi declarado no arquivo de layout:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/dialog_participant_name_auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:hint="@string/dialog_participant_auto_name"
    android:textColorHint="@color/hint_text_color"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Funciona quase que perfeitamente, mas ele duplica o valor da busca. Por exemplo, se eu salvar um contato com nome "Fulano" e email "fulano@gmail.com", e pesquisar por "F", o `AutoCompleteTextView` me retorna dois items:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já verificou se realmente não está repetindo no banco de dados?! São contatos do celular ou você criou uma tabela usando sqlite? Tente usar distinct

Comment: São contatos que eu adicionei em meu BD usando sqlite, Mesmo com o DISTINCT o problema persiste. Acredito que seja por causa da pesquisa duplicada mesmo

Comment: Pelo menos no codigo que você está mostrando aqui na sua pergunta, não encontrei nada que possa estar duplicando. Talvez seja em outra parte do seu código ou a duplicação esteja mesmo no seu banco. Geralmente o uo do distinct sempre funciona.